# How to provide favicon.png in an Angular app instead of favicon.ico?

Tags: angular, favicon

I created a new Angular app with:

```
ng new ...
```

And I can view the application with:

```
ng serve --open
```

I removed the default `src/favicon.ico` and replaced it with `src/favicon.png`. I also opened `src/index.html` and changed the appropriate line to read:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

This doesn't seem to have worked. Issuing a GET request for `/favicon.png` simply returns the content from `src/index.html`. Restarting `ng serve` makes no difference.

How can I make this file accessible to the application?

Comment: try by by Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make a PNG image with same name (i.e. *favicon.png*) and change the name in these files.

*index.html*

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png" />
```

*angular.json*

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.png" 
  "src/assets",
]
```

In older version of Angular (prior to v.7), the latter file is *angular-cli.json*

```
"assets": [
  "favicon.png" 
  "assets",
]
```

Afterwards, depending on browser, version OS etc.

1. restart the app
2. restart the browser
3. clean cache

Comment: I swear I ran a text search for `favicon` in the project directory. Perhaps it skipped hidden files. Thanks!

Comment: From Angular 6 upwards the file that needs to change its angular.json and not angular-cli.json